# How to query a column which value is null in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA namedQuery to select data from DB.

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Concept.findByRefTableNull", query = "SELECT c FROM Concept c WHERE c.conceptName = :conceptName and c.refTable = :refTable"),

///
 List<Concept> attributeList 
                = em.createNamedQuery("Concept.findByRefTableNull")
                .setParameter("conceptName", "student").
                setParameter("refTable", null).
                getResultList();

        System.out.println(attributeList.size()); //return 0
```

The List size is 0, but I am sure it should have records. The reason is the refTable. How to query a column which value is null in JPA ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just change your query to

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Concept.findByRefTableNull", query = "SELECT c FROM Concept c WHERE c.conceptName = :conceptName and c.refTable IS NULL"),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Criteri Api , like this :

```
private Specification<Object> nullData(String field) {
    return (root, query, cb) ->
            cb.isNull(cb.lower(root.get(field)));
}
```

Comment: How can i solve this issue using queryDSL

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a Spring Data JPA feature only but I just write a method in the repository interface of the form findByFieldName(Type field) where fieldName is the name of the column I need to do a null check on. I then use this method and pass null as a parameter.

Comment: That won't work when your argument data type is a primitive one.

Comment: @Raj Yes, this is why most people recommend not to use primitive data types for fields in entity classes. However, for primitives one needs to define defaults like e.g. 0 or -1 for integers, and let JPA search for it.

Answer (score -1):

i would avoid Queries altogether - it pretty much negates the sense of persistence-abstraction. Create dynamic queries via the [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) instead, this will ensure portability AND you will be able to switch databases to some extent without much hassle

Comment: Having JPQL queries is still an abstraction layer and allows you to switch the database as well as when using criteria.