# querydsl spring data jpa operator precedence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {
   List<Item> findByNameAndDescriptionIsNullOrDescription(String name, String desc); 
 }
```

In the native Query, the `where` condition of `findByNameAndDescriptionIsNullOrDescription` is translated to

```
where item0_.NAME=? and (item0_.DESC is null) or item0_.DESC=?
```

I need to have **`where item0_.NAME=? and (item0_.DESC is null or item0_.DESC=?)`**

I am using the following

- spring-data-commons-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar
- (i)hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar, (ii) hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar offered by JBOSS EAP 6.3

Comment: and the relevance of QueryDSL to this question? Native query will be an SQL query.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you can't do that.

Spring Data querydsl is used only for simple SQL queries and if you need something more complex use `@Query` annotation.

It also would be easier for other developers to understand what query you used instead of analyzing your method name.

Answer (score 3):

`And` operator has priority over to `or` operator. Changing this priority or using pharenthesis in JPA queries is not possible but you can try to spread `and` operator to over others:

```
findByNameAndDescriptionOrNameOrDescriptionIsNull
```

Now your logic evulated from:

```
item0_.NAME=? and (item0_.DESC is null or item0_.DESC=?)
```

to:

```
(item0_.NAME=? and item0_.DESC=?) or (item0_.NAME=? and item0_.DESC is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the need to add 2nd argument desc.. Just use below:

List findByNameAndDescription(String name, String desc);

Even if u pass desc argument null, u ll get desired results.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325213/how-to-query-a-column-which-value-is-null-in-jpa